# How to say "money laundering" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, neologism, money, economics

How does one say "[money laundering](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121171#eid36244231)" or "to launder money" in Latin?

Latin does have words for different types of money (St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 32 a. 7](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS032.html#SSQ32A7THEP1) co.):

- *turpe lucrum* (filthy lucre)
- *mammona* (riches)
- *illicite acquisitum* (ill-gotten)

But "to launder money" is of very recent coinage; it "arose from the Watergate inquiry in the United States in 1973–4." ([*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106279#eid39808388)).

Comment: This is a modern concept which is only relevant to banking systems where the contents of bank accounts are being scrutinized.

Comment: @TylerDurden I doubt the concept is modern. Banking isn't modern. The Knights Templar, for example, ran an international banking system for funding the crusades.

Comment: Roads and lanterns aren't modern but the Romans still didn't have a word for traffic lights. Money laundering as a concept was invented in the 20th century. *Lavatio pecuniae* has some currency in Neo-Latin.

Comment: Cicero has a proverb, [ill-gotten grains soon waste](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh12841). Perhaps you could base it on that with the meaning being something like "ill-gotten money made true/legitimate", or something along those lines.